# How to send a continuous stream of data with asp .net core web api?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

I want to send a continuous stream of data to the client. Let's say i have a web api service route `[Route(/bla/continuous/data)]`. The client expects continuous stream data over http from that api, is there a way to do that? For example, this code i am trying in this route `[Route(/bla/continuous/data)]`

```
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializeObj = new 
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(CachedResponse));
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
serializeObj.Serialize(memoryStream, events);
var xmlDoc = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlDoc);
xDoc.StripNamespace();
var xmlReader = xDoc.CreateReader();
xmlReader.MoveToContent();
var response = Regex.Replace(xmlReader.ReadInnerXml(), @"\s+", "");
```

Now at the end the response type is string type, but i guess thats not continuous flow, i wanna be able to send that response continuously if that make sense, not sure if i am even explaining right way!!

Comment: Try WebSockets or SignalR

Answer (score -2):

You must use pub/sub pattern, you can use any message broker for that